# Elasticsearch UpdateByQueryRequest using XContentBuilder

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have `UpdateRequest` for which I can set `XContentBuilder` with : `updateRequest.doc(XContentBuilder);`. Is it possible to perform the same action for `UpdateByQueryRequest`? If not can I transform `XContentBuilder` to `Script`? What are alternatives to `Script`?

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja actually I ended up converting it to Map than passing as param in Script

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of [Elasticsearch's UpdateByQueryRequest](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/reindex/UpdateByQueryRequest.java#L181), you notice, what you wanted is possible using the below method, as you can notice, it can covert the `script` to `XContentBuilder`.

```
@Override
    public XContentBuilder toXContent(XContentBuilder builder, Params params) throws IOException {
        builder.startObject();
        if (getScript() != null) {
            builder.field("script");
            getScript().toXContent(builder, params);
        }
        getSearchRequest().source().innerToXContent(builder, params);
        builder.endObject();
        return builder;
    }
```

[ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html) didn't have the sample example of converting `script` to `XContentBuilder`, but as method is present, you can simply make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is converting to Map, and passing it as a script:

```
Map<String, Object> params = mapper.readValue(Strings.toString(XContentBuilder), Map.class);
    UpdateByQueryRequest updateRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest("document");
 updateRequest.setScript(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE,
                "painless",
                "ctx._source.document = params.document",
                params));
```

I will leave the question open in case someone finds a better solution.